# Передать текст в TextWriter

Tags: c#

Прошу помощи в задании и заранее благодарю.
Есть обычный класс, в котором задана глобальная переменная типа `TextWriter globalWriter`

Есть (как я понимаю) конструктор:

```
public Task(TextWriter writer)
{
    globalWriter = writer;
}
```

А также есть ещё один метод(в этом же классе), в котором есть переменная типа `string`, которую *нужно записать в globalWriter*. Конечно, я уже попыталась почитать про абстрактный класс TextWriter, но так никак и не могу понять, что именно от меня нужно :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не называйте свои методы и классы как существующие классы в .NET, это сбивает с толку, например [есть вот такой класс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) `Task`. Давайте методам говорящие названия, по которым станет понятно, что он делает, например `CopyText`.

И вы не можете скопировать данные из одного `TextWriter` в другой, потому что `TextWriter` может только писать, читать он не может, поэтому один из двух должен быть `TextReader`.

```cs
public CopyText(TextReader reader)
{
    globalWriter.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Данный метод прочитает весь текст из `TextReader` и запишет его в `TextWriter`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!